# I left my non-stick pan in the oven while it was preheating, can I still use it?

Tags: oven, non-stick, teflon

Long story short, I left my non-stick pan in the oven while it was preheating. Left it in there for about 20 - 30 minutes, including 15 minutes at 375 degrees Fahrenheit. Just wondering if I can still use it or if I have to toss it. Thanks for your time, any input is appreciated!

EDIT: It's a T-fal Viva Frying Pan.

EDIT 2: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [T-FAL](https://www.t-falusa.com/medias/T-fal-USA-IFU-FOR-COOKWARE-.pdf?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8NjU3Mzk4fGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL3BkZnxoYzEvaDhjLzg5MzE2NjQ2MjU2OTQucGRmfDA5ZWJjZDczZTE2MjM1ZmViMmQyNzJkZTA4YzMwYzg0Y2NhYWYxNDA3MmExOGFmNTZhMTU2YmQyMzJjNjFlZmY) site:

> • Oven safe to 500°F/260°C if handles are all stainless steel. Oven safe to 350°F/175°C if handles have any phenolic, plastic parts.
>   Oven safe to 400°F/204°C if handles have any silicone parts.

So the pan itself should be fine, but the handles can be damaged.  No need to toss it just because you're worried about the coating being changed.

Answer (score 2):

Short story, yes.

It should be fine because most nonstick pans can go up to around **500°F (260°C)** and still not be damaged. That doesn't mean you should make a habit out of it, you should try to avoid it getting to high temps especially while not cooking something in it.